# Multithread python count week days several dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-multithreading

Hi everyone I'm trying to use multithread in python

```
def get_weekday_data(t_index,file_name):
    """
   get dates (columna Date/Time).
    """
    #
    logging.info("[T{}]\tStarted with url {}".format(t_index, file_name))
    data=pd.read_csv(path+file_name)
    data['Date/Time']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date/Time'], 
    infer_datetime_format=True) 
    week_day_data=pd.DataFrame(data['Date/Time'].apply(lambda x: 
    x.strftime('%A')))
    week_day_data_2=pd.DataFrame(week_day_data['Date/Time'].value_counts())
    week_day_data_2.reset_index(inplace=True)
    week_day_data_2.sort_values('index',inplace=True)
    print(week_day_data_2)



  logging.info("[T{}]\tEnd".format(t_index))
  return week_day_data_2
```

I have this function and I wnat to apply the function to 6 data sets using multithread
I try the following but I dont know how to concat de results of each thread. I m learning how to use multithread and multiprocesses.
But I dont know how to obtain the output of each thread

```
%%time
threads = []

#  6 threads execute get_weekday_data 

for i, num in enumerate(files_to_read):
    print('now')
    thread = Thread(target= get_weekday_data, args=(i,num))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Espera a que los 6 threads finalicen
for i, thread in enumerate(threads):
    logging.info("[M]\tWaiting to join thread {}".format(i))
    thread.join()
    logging.info("[M]\tThread {} joined!".format(i))

logging.info("[M]\tDONE!")
```

Comment: files_to_read is the list with the files names

Comment: Do you have a problem with this code? does it show any errors?

Comment: No errors but I want to get the results of othreads in a data frame or dictionary. Because this code is doing but I dont know how to get what Im doing

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend using `joblib`, it's much easier to use. You can install it using:

```
pip install joblib
```

And you can use it simply like so:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed


result = Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend="threading")(
            delayed(get_weekday_data)(idx, file_name) \
                for idx, file_name in enumerate(files_to_read))
```

`result` is a list of all data sorted based on insertion. You can even control how many threads running together from the `n_jobs` argument

Answer (score 0):

You could use the map function of [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) or [ProcessPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor)

Here's a possible implementation

```py
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = executor.map(get_weekday_data, range(len(files_to_read)), files_to_read)
```